# How to link checkboxes between Treeview & Listview ? VSC

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've created treeView1 listView1,
made them present the same folder structure,
and set checkboxes to true.

**How do I link them so checking a file or folder in one view, checks the corresponding file or folder in the other. Essentially mirroring them.**

I can't find the solution via google / microsoft library.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to create a connection beteween the nodes and the items.

Let's assume you can use the `Tags` of both..

Here I fill the two controls:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.Columns.Add("No");
        listView1.View = View.Details;

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            // keep a temporary reference of the new nodes/items..
            ListViewItem lvi = listView1.Items.Add("Item " + i);
            TreeNode tn =  treeView1.Nodes.Add("Item " + i);
            // ..and store them in the respective tags:
            lvi.Tag = tn;
            tn.Tag = lvi;
        }
    }
```

Now sych'ing them is easy:

```
    private void treeView1_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Node.Tag != null)
            ((ListViewItem)(e.Node.Tag)).Checked = e.Node.Checked;
    }

    private void listView1_ItemChecked(object sender, ItemCheckedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.Tag != null) 
           ((TreeNode)(e.Item.Tag)).Checked = e.Item.Checked;
    }
```

Any more complicated rules, like checking sub-nodes would have to be defined first, then, as usual in a tree, you would have to write a recursive function..